# PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) in Window

Tags: security, pam, apache-drill

I am trying to configure PAM in Window 10 Operating System for `Authentication in Apache Drill.`

Whiling running Drill. I got following error:-

> Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit:
>   org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Problem in
>   finding the native library of JPAM (Pluggable Authenticator Module
>   API). Make sure to set Drillbit JVM option 'java.library.path' to
>   point to the directory where the native JPAM exists.:Could not
>   initialize class net.sf.jpam.Pam (state=,code=0)

`Can Anyone Tell Me, How to Configure PAM in Window.? Or What I am doing wrong.?`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jpam native library for Windows. Unfortunately, it does not appear to exist with only support for Linux, Solaris and Mac. You could try compiling the library yourself , since the source is available.